# Unable to run my Spring MVC project on tomcat 8.5 and 7.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am having problem running my spring mvc project i tried different solutions provided on stack overflow and other community sites but still unable to resolve the issue, i don't know what exactly the problem is, What options I have tried are,
i. Changed my eclipse version from Mars to eclipse Photon
ii. I have been told to change jdk version as i am using only jdk 8.65 only i don't have other versions installed.
iii. I changed my tomcat server from 7 to 8.5 still getting the same error.

following is the stack trace i get while running the project.

[image: Beans configuration file]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns="http://oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"     
        version="3.0">
      <display-name>Spring MVC Configuration Starter</display-name>
      <servlet>
        <display-name>dispatcher</display-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
      </servlet>
      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>SpringMVCConfigurationStarter</groupId>
        <artifactId>SpringMVCConfigurationStarter</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>war</packaging>
        <name>Spring MVC</name>
        <dependencies>

            <!-- Spring -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                <version>LATEST</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Servlet API -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>


        <build>
            <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </project>
```

```
    SEVERE: A child container failed during start
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/SpringMVCConfigurationStarter]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:941)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1421)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1411)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/SpringMVCConfigurationStarter]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
        ... 6 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Container name cannot be null
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.setName(ContainerBase.java:507)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureContext(ContextConfig.java:1329)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1180)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:765)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 6 more

    Jun 05, 2019 2:08:26 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
    SEVERE: A child container failed during start
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:941)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:681)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:353)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:493)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1421)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1411)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:949)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 6 more

    Jun 05, 2019 2:08:26 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
    SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:681)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:353)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:493)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 7 more
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 9 more
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:949)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 11 more
```

Comment: Add all information as text not as link to an image

Comment: Hi Jens! I have included my web.xml file and pom.xml file code, thanks

Comment: Please add all information as text/code. The full stacktrace/log the images are unreadable. Also in your pom never use the `LATEST` version as you will get the newest version, which suddenly might break things, use a specific version.

Comment: Hi M Deinum i tried with specific versions as well, and i have included my stack trace as well pls check that out i don't know what's wrong with tomcat i have tried with 7.0 and 8.5 but the same issue occurs even i changed eclipse versions as well...thanks for the help

Comment: If it fails on one with a severe exception like this it will fail on others as well. Changing the IDE will never be of help if something fails on the server. Either your server is borked, or you mesed around with the `server.xml` (or the settings in Eclipse for the tomcat container). Or maybe you have a `Context.xml` in your project somehwere which interferes with properly starting tomcat. The issue is in your tomcat config, and only changing the tomcat version will not help, if you keep using the same tomcat confiugration.

Comment: Have you tried, starting tomcat and then deploy your application? So remove it from the tomcat webapp directory and manually drop the war file after starting tomcat. See what happens.

Comment: M Deinum! thank you for you kind suggestions yeah i had tried those things as well like cleaning the working directory, deleting complete web app from the tomcat and the thing that you mentioned for server.xml and context.xml i did'nt touch them, but now the problem has been solved i have figured out the problem i was facing thank you for your time and valuable comments..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your quick responses, I have figured out the issue i was facing,
there are few things i suppose that were causing error,

1. I converted my project from dynamic web project to a Maven project.
2. I forget to remove libraries that i added in the lib directory (Most probably this was the main issue)
3. in my web.xml file i put display-name tag mistakenly which should be servlet-name inside servlet tag.

My current web.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
    
    version="3.0">
 
  <display-name>Spring MVC Configuration Starter</display-name>
    
  <servlet>
   <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
   <init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml</param-value>
   </init-param>
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  
  <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  
</web-app>
```

pom.xml

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>SpringMVCConfigurationStarter</groupId>
 <artifactId>SpringMVCConfigurationStarter</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <packaging>war</packaging>
 <name>Spring MVC</name>
 <dependencies>
 
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.6.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

 
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.6.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>


  <!-- JSTL -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
   <version>1.2</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- for compile only, your container should have this -->
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  
  </dependencies>


 <build>
  <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3</version>
    <configuration>
     <source>1.8</source>
     <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
   <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
     <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
     <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>
</project>
```

[Result after successfully running the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUTgW.png)